# Python: get properties of class elements listed in a superior class

Tags: python

i have the following problem in python. I declare a class *element* with some property and a class *network* with a list *population*.

Now I populate the network with objects of class *element*: e1,e2 and e3. When I try to get the properties of the elements populating the network, I get an error.

Can you pls help me understanding the issues?

```
import sys

class element:
    def __init__(self):
        self.property = 1

    def getProperty(self):
        return(self.property)

class network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.population = []

    def addElement(self, element):
        self.population.append([element])

    def getElementProp(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.population)):
            #print(self.population[i])
            print(self.population[i].getProperty())

print(sys.version_info)

e1 = element()
e2 = element()
e3 = element()

net = network()
net.addElement(e1)
net.addElement(e2)
net.addElement(e3)

net.getElementProp()

**Output:**

line 20, in getElementProp
    print((self.population[i]).getProperty())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getProperty
```

Comment: Why the brackets in `self.population.append([element])`?

Comment: Learn to use a debugger ... you may find it better in the long run ...

Answer (score 3):

You are appending a list object containing an `element` instance while you should be appending the instance directly to your `population` list:

```
def addElement(self, element):
    self.population.append(element)
```

You could also `expand` your method to take one or more elements at the same time, without the need to make repeated calls:

```
def addElements(self, *elements):
    self.population.extend(elements)

...

net = network()
net.addElements(e1, e2, e3)
```

More so, in your `getElementProp` method, it is more [**Pythonic**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-pythonic) to iterate on the elements directly rather than use `range(len(...))` with a later list indexing:

```
def getElementProp(self):
    for e in self.population:
        print(e.getProperty())
```